# Queueing TFS builds via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs, build

TFS2012 with a one 2010 build controller with one 2010 build agent. Also have one 2012 build controller with multiple 2012 build agents.

We have multiple builds for multiple versions of our software. The builds are named according to a convention e.g. Foo_version_1_0 and Foo_version_2_0.

When I run this code on my local machine, all the builds are queued. When I run this code manually on a 2012 build agent, the builds are queued. When I run this code manually on a 2010 build agent, no builds are queued. When the code is executed as part of a triggered build in TFS (either on the 2010 or 2012 controller/agent), it doesn't queue any builds and errors out with my custom exception saying no definitions returned from TFS.

My questions:

Is the $buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions() function an administrator function only? I.e. if a non-admin user account (like TFSService) runs it, it won't be able to get the data from the TFS api?

Is the $buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions() a new function that is only available in 2012?

Is there another way of doing this that will work? Previously, we had all our build names hard coded - this is not a viable way forward for us.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client")

$serverName="http://tfs:8080/tfs"
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($serverName)
$buildserver = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])

$buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions("FooProject") | foreach {
if ($_.EndsWith("version_1_0"))
{
echo "Queueing build: $_.Name"
$buildServer.QueueBuild($buildServer.GetBuildDefinition("FooProject",$_.Name))
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: removed `$buildDefinitions = $buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions("FooProject").Name`, replaced it with `$buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions("FooProject") | foreach...`

Builds are now queued programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API hasn't changed, and I suppose that both agents are using the same account.

The line

> $buildDefinitions = $buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions("FooProject").Name

seems wrong: the Name property get will raise an exception for an empty result.

Comment: I've updated the query - didn't make a difference to the outcome of the script. No builds are queued when the PowerShell script is executed as part of a triggered/queued build.

Answer (score 2):

You can also utilize one of the built in APIs, to prevent downloading dll binaries.

The following will work for

**TFS 2017:**

https://github.com/sameer-kumar/adhoc-posh/blob/master/QueueTfsBuild.ps1

```
$rootTfsUri = "http://myTFS:8080/tfs"
$collectionName = "Default"
$projectName = "Project1"
$tfsUri = $rootTfsUri + "/" + $collectionName + "/" + $projectName
$buildDefinition = "DevCI-vnext"
$buildDefinitionUri = "$tfsUri/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=3.1&name=$buildDefinition" 

# first get build definition id
$buildResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $buildDefinitionUri -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get -Verbose -UseBasicParsing -ContentType "application/json" 
$buildResponseAsJson = $buildResponse.Content | convertfrom-json
$buildDefinitionId = $buildResponseAsJson.value.id

# Now queue this build definition
$requestContentString = @"
{
    "definition": {
        "id" : "$buildDefinitionId"
    }
}
"@

$buildUri = "$tfsUri/_apis/build/builds?api-version=3.1"
$buildResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $buildUri -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Post -Verbose -UseBasicParsing -ContentType "application/json" -Body $requestContentString
$buildNumber = ($buildResponse.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).buildNumber
```

**TFS 2015**

Utilizes a slightly different structure where uri definition replace with this,

```
$buildDefinitionUri = "$tfsUri/_apis/Build/builds?api-version=2.0&name=$buildDefinition"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
# Set your variables
$baseUrl = "<BASE-URL>" # e.g., https://tfs.some.thing.com/tfs
$organization = "<ORGANIZATION>"
$project = "<PROJECT>"
$apiVersion = "<API-VERSION>" # I use 2.2
$definitionId = "<BUILD-DEFINITION-ID>"
$username = "<USERNAME>"
$personalAccessToken = "<PAT>" # replace with your personal access token

# Set the URL
$url = "$baseUrl/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=$apiVersion"

# Create a PowerShell credential object with your username and personal access token
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$personalAccessToken)))

# Create headers for the request
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $token)}

# Create the JSON body for the request
$body = @{
    definition = @{
        id = $definitionId
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Make the REST API call
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $body -Headers $headers -ContentType application/json
```

To get the PAT, login to TFS -> click on your profile -> Security -> Personal access tokens, then add a new token with all scopes selected.