# How does one queue a Team Foundation build from the command line?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

`tf.exe` gives access to pretty much everything Team Foundation can do in terms of source control, but doesn't have an obvious way to queue a build from the command line (or from a script). Is there a means of doing this shipping with Team Foundation, or a third party tool that can do this?

Comment: I typed *team foundation queue build* into Google and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181722.aspx came up as the first result *Queue a public build if you want to build the most recent version of the source code in the version control server. To queue a public build at a command prompt, use the TFSBuild start command.*

Comment: Dear "off-topic" close-voter: one of the bullets in the FAQ is `•software tools commonly used by programmers`

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Then post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the TFS API on a small program, like this Powershell script:

[Queueing TFS builds via PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820861/queueing-tfs-builds-via-powershell)

Or this C# code:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/03/25/tfs2010-queuing-a-build-from-code-with-custom-process-parameter-values.aspx

Answer (score 0):

2.At the command prompt type:

Copy

<root>:>TFSBuild start http://server01:8080 AdventureWorks Nightlies

Where the Team Foundation Server is the server specified by the build definition, "Nightlies" and the built files are saved in the build drop location, which is also specified by the build definition. The <root> specifies the drive, usually "C". The "http://server01" specifies the URL for the Team Foundation server, "AdventureWorks" specifies the team project, and "Nightlies" specifies the build definition

Comment: I found TFSBuild.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE